# ArcMap raster calculator raising negative values to a power

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a raster calculator expression:

```
Power("dataset.tif",1.5)
```

where dataset is float, and has some negative values.

When I run this expression in raster calculator, all of the negative values within the dataset have an output of 'nodata'.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What do you want to see? The answer you have IS correct?

Comment: Raising a negative number to a non-integer power is "complex"... ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Python help file:

> If both `x` and `y` are finite, `x` is negative, and `y` is not an integer
>   then `pow(x, y)` is undefined, and raises ValueError.

May be this is the source of your error? The `x` needs to be a positive integer if you want `y` to be a double?

Answer (score -1):

I can't find this in Esri doc, but [this blog](https://karlhennermann.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/arcgis-pitfall-of-the-day-exponentiation-with-rasters-and-tables/) suggests that the `**` operator means "to the power of" so `"dataset.tif" ** 1.5` may get you what you want.

Comment: No, `"dataset.tif" ** 1.5` will get exactly the same result as `Power("dataset.tif", 1.5)`